# Installing Debian but can't boot

Tags: debian, boot, grub, uefi

I'm installing Debian testing on a SSD, there is a pre-existing EFI ESP partition from windows installation, the disk uses GPT partitioning. Problem is after it finishes installing it won't boot linux or grub. In my motherboard UEFI boot order I see a japenese sign that appeared after the installation, when I try to boot on it it won't do anything. Any idea ?

efibootmgr -v

```
root@ubuntu:~# efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 000B
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0002,0006,0007,0008,000A,000B,000C,0000
Boot0000* debian    VenHw(99e275e7-75a0-4b37-a2e6-c5385e6c00cb)
Boot0002* Windows Boot Manager  HD(2,GPT,b790d826-8e17-4ec7-b89b-12d783ec520e,0xe1800,0x32000)/File(\EFI\MICROSOFT\BOOT\BOOTMGFW.EFI)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...9................
Boot0006* Hard Drive    BBS(HD,,0x0)..GO..NO..........N.1.-.S.a.m.s.u.n.g. .S.S.D. .9.5.0. .P.R.O. .5.1.2.G.B....................A........................1.N........>.;......N..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.N.1.-.S.a.m.s.u.n.g. .S.S.D. .9.5.0. .P.R.O. .5.1.2.G.B........BO..NO........o.W.D.C. .W.D.6.0.0.1.F.F.W.X.-.6.8.Z.3.9.N.0....................A...........................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L. . . . .W. .-.D.X.W.1.4.7.D.L.5.8.N.5.H........BO
Boot0007* CD/DVD Drive  BBS(CDROM,,0x0)..GO..NO........o.A.T.A.P.I. . . .i.H.A.S.1.2.4. . . .E....................A...........................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.5.3.4.2.0.7. .3.L.2.4.8.3.4.0.5.4.9.9.8........BO
Boot0008* USB   BBS(USB,,0x0)..GO..NO........i.V.e.r.b.a.t.i.m.S.T.O.R.E. .N. .G.O. .1.1.0.0....................A.............................6..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.1.3.1.1.0.4.0.0.0.0.0.0.4.3.2.4........BO..NO........}. .M.E.M.U.P. .1...0.0....................A.............................J..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.0.9.0.2.1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.5.4.8........BO
Boot000A* UEFI: ATAPI   iHAS124   E PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x11,0x4)/Sata(2,65535,0)/CDROM(0,0x33f,0xdffb0)/HD(1,MBR,0x0,0x20,0x7fe0)..BO
Boot000B* UEFI: VerbatimSTORE N GO 1100 PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1a,0x0)/USB(1,0)/USB(2,0)/HD(1,MBR,0x0,0x800,0x1dd9000)..BO
Boot000C* UEFI:  MEMUP 1.00 PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1d,0x0)/USB(1,0)/USB(5,0)/HD(1,MBR,0x0,0x800,0xeeb800)..BO
```

tree EFI :

```
root@ubuntu:/# mount /dev/nvme0n1p2 /mnt
root@ubuntu:/# ls mnt
EFI
root@ubuntu:/# tree /mnt
/mnt
└── EFI
    ├── Boot
    │   └── bootx64.efi
    ├── debian
    │   └── grubx64.efi
    └── Microsoft
        ├── Boot
        │   ├── BCD
        │   ├── BCD.LOG
        │   ├── BCD.LOG1
        │   ├── BCD.LOG2
        │   ├── bg-BG
        │   │   ├── bootmgfw.efi.mui
        │   │   └── bootmgr.efi.mui
        │   ├── bootmgfw.efi
        │   ├── bootmgr.efi
        │   ├── BOOTSTAT.DAT
        │   ├── boot.stl
        │   ├── cs-CZ
        │   │   ├── bootmgfw.efi.mui
        │   │   ├── bootmgr.efi.mui
        │   │   └── memtest.efi.mui
        │   ├── da-DK
        │   │   ├── bootmgfw.efi.mui
        │   │   ├── bootmgr.efi.mui
        │   │   └── memtest.efi.mui
        │   ├── de-DE
        │   │   ├── bootmgfw.efi.mui
        │   │   ├── bootmgr.efi.mui
        │   │   └── memtest.efi.mui
        │   ├── el-GR
        │   │   ├── bootmgfw.efi.mui
        │   │   ├── bootmgr.efi.mui
        │   │   └── memtest.efi.mui
        │   ├── en-GB
        │   │   ├── bootmgfw.efi.mui
        │   │   └── bootmgr.efi.mui
        │   ├── en-US
        │   │   ├── bootmgfw.efi.mui
        │   │   ├── bootmgr.efi.mui
        │   │   └── memtest.efi.mui
        │   ├── es-ES
        │   │   ├── bootmgfw.efi.mui
        │   │   ├── bootmgr.efi.mui
        │   │   └── memtest.efi.mui
        │   ├── es-MX
        │   │   ├── bootmgfw.efi.mui
        │   │   └── bootmgr.efi.mui
        │   ├── et-EE
        │   │   ├── bootmgfw.efi.mui
        │   │   └── bootmgr.efi.mui
        │   ├── fi-FI
        │   │   ├── bootmgfw.efi.mui
        │   │   ├── bootmgr.efi.mui
        │   │   └── memtest.efi.mui
        │   ├── Fonts
        │   │   ├── chs_boot.ttf
        │   │   ├── cht_boot.ttf
        │   │   ├── jpn_boot.ttf
        │   │   ├── kor_boot.ttf
        │   │   ├── malgun_boot.ttf
        │   │   ├── malgunn_boot.ttf
        │   │   ├── meiryo_boot.ttf
        │   │   ├── meiryon_boot.ttf
        │   │   ├── msjh_boot.ttf
        │   │   ├── msjhn_boot.ttf
        │   │   ├── msyh_boot.ttf
        │   │   ├── msyhn_boot.ttf
        │   │   ├── segmono_boot.ttf
        │   │   ├── segoen_slboot.ttf
        │   │   ├── segoe_slboot.ttf
        │   │   └── wgl4_boot.ttf
        │   ├── fr-CA
        │   │   ├── bootmgfw.efi.mui
        │   │   └── bootmgr.efi.mui
        │   ├── fr-FR
        │   │   ├── bootmgfw.efi.mui
        │   │   ├── bootmgr.efi.mui
        │   │   └── memtest.efi.mui
        │   ├── hr-HR
        │   │   ├── bootmgfw.efi.mui
        │   │   └── bootmgr.efi.mui
        │   ├── hu-HU
        │   │   ├── bootmgfw.efi.mui
        │   │   ├── bootmgr.efi.mui
        │   │   └── memtest.efi.mui
        │   ├── it-IT
        │   │   ├── bootmgfw.efi.mui
        │   │   ├── bootmgr.efi.mui
        │   │   └── memtest.efi.mui
        │   ├── ja-JP
        │   │   ├── bootmgfw.efi.mui
        │   │   ├── bootmgr.efi.mui
        │   │   └── memtest.efi.mui
        │   ├── kd_02_10df.dll
        │   ├── kd_02_10ec.dll
        │   ├── kd_02_1137.dll
        │   ├── kd_02_14e4.dll
        │   ├── kd_02_15b3.dll
        │   ├── kd_02_1969.dll
        │   ├── kd_02_19a2.dll
        │   ├── kd_02_8086.dll
        │   ├── kd_07_1415.dll
        │   ├── kd_0C_8086.dll
        │   ├── kdstub.dll
        │   ├── ko-KR
        │   │   ├── bootmgfw.efi.mui
        │   │   ├── bootmgr.efi.mui
        │   │   └── memtest.efi.mui
        │   ├── lt-LT
        │   │   ├── bootmgfw.efi.mui
        │   │   └── bootmgr.efi.mui
        │   ├── lv-LV
        │   │   ├── bootmgfw.efi.mui
        │   │   └── bootmgr.efi.mui
        │   ├── memtest.efi
        │   ├── nb-NO
        │   │   ├── bootmgfw.efi.mui
        │   │   ├── bootmgr.efi.mui
        │   │   └── memtest.efi.mui
        │   ├── nl-NL
        │   │   ├── bootmgfw.efi.mui
        │   │   ├── bootmgr.efi.mui
        │   │   └── memtest.efi.mui
        │   ├── pl-PL
        │   │   ├── bootmgfw.efi.mui
        │   │   ├── bootmgr.efi.mui
        │   │   └── memtest.efi.mui
        │   ├── pt-BR
        │   │   ├── bootmgfw.efi.mui
        │   │   ├── bootmgr.efi.mui
        │   │   └── memtest.efi.mui
        │   ├── pt-PT
        │   │   ├── bootmgfw.efi.mui
        │   │   ├── bootmgr.efi.mui
        │   │   └── memtest.efi.mui
        │   ├── qps-ploc
        │   │   ├── bootmgfw.efi.mui
        │   │   ├── bootmgr.efi.mui
        │   │   └── memtest.efi.mui
        │   ├── Resources
        │   │   ├── bootres.dll
        │   │   └── fr-FR
        │   │       └── bootres.dll.mui
        │   ├── ro-RO
        │   │   ├── bootmgfw.efi.mui
        │   │   └── bootmgr.efi.mui
        │   ├── ru-RU
        │   │   ├── bootmgfw.efi.mui
        │   │   ├── bootmgr.efi.mui
        │   │   └── memtest.efi.mui
        │   ├── sk-SK
        │   │   ├── bootmgfw.efi.mui
        │   │   └── bootmgr.efi.mui
        │   ├── sl-SI
        │   │   ├── bootmgfw.efi.mui
        │   │   └── bootmgr.efi.mui
        │   ├── sr-Latn-CS
        │   │   ├── bootmgfw.efi.mui
        │   │   ├── bootmgr.efi.mui
        │   │   └── memtest.efi.mui
        │   ├── sr-Latn-RS
        │   │   ├── bootmgfw.efi.mui
        │   │   └── bootmgr.efi.mui
        │   ├── sv-SE
        │   │   ├── bootmgfw.efi.mui
        │   │   ├── bootmgr.efi.mui
        │   │   └── memtest.efi.mui
        │   ├── tr-TR
        │   │   ├── bootmgfw.efi.mui
        │   │   ├── bootmgr.efi.mui
        │   │   └── memtest.efi.mui
        │   ├── uk-UA
        │   │   ├── bootmgfw.efi.mui
        │   │   └── bootmgr.efi.mui
        │   ├── zh-CN
        │   │   ├── bootmgfw.efi.mui
        │   │   ├── bootmgr.efi.mui
        │   │   └── memtest.efi.mui
        │   ├── zh-HK
        │   │   ├── bootmgfw.efi.mui
        │   │   ├── bootmgr.efi.mui
        │   │   └── memtest.efi.mui
        │   └── zh-TW
        │       ├── bootmgfw.efi.mui
        │       ├── bootmgr.efi.mui
        │       └── memtest.efi.mui
        └── Recovery
            ├── BCD
            ├── BCD.LOG
            ├── BCD.LOG1
            └── BCD.LOG2
```

Comment: Not sure is what you need but I got it working creating a [BIOS boot partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS_boot_partition) as first partition

Comment: @Alex what do you mean, I boot into live CD convert the first partition to BIOS boot partition and try to reinstall Debian ?

Comment: Before converting the already existing I would try creating a new one, 1M should be enough (I think being the first partition is not a requirement).

Comment: [GRUB development team generally recommends embedding GRUB before the first partition, unless you have special requirements](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/BIOS-installation.html) Again, I'm not sure this is what you need.

Comment: Did you disable Secure Boot? What is the output of `efibootmgr -v`? What is the content of the EFI folder on your ESP partition?

Comment: @JPW added the result of `efibootmgr -v`

Comment: I think your debian entry is wrong. Can you also post the contents of your ESP partition? (Mount it using some live CD and execute `tree` on the mount point; it's probably the only FAT32 partition in your system)

Comment: @JPW I didn't touch to the debian entry so the installer would have made it wrong ? I edited my post with tree EFI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, it seems that something went wrong with the installation of GRUB. I would try to create a new firmware boot entry first:

```
efibootmgr -c -d /dev/disk/by-uuid/b790d826-8e17-4ec7-b89b-12d783ec520e -p 2 -l /EFI/debian/grubx64.efi -L "Debian"
```

(for more information see e.g. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#efibootmgr)

This will not touch other boot options and can be removed if it didn't work.

If this doesn't fix your installation, you can try to re-install GRUB. You can do this by booting a live CD (preferably one which matches your installation) and `chroot` to your installation. Afterwards you should run `grub-install` and `update-grub` (for more information, again, see e.g. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#Installation_2; though you probably can't use arch-chroot with a Debian installation).

Comment: wow the `efibootmgr` actually worked (just had to replace `by-uuid` with `by-partuuid` ) I have to retry this with encrypted partition and accept your answer just after. Does it mean that the Debian installer put the boot mgr in the wrong place ?

Comment: `efibootmgr` does not install the bootloader; it only creates a boot entry with the BIOS/firmware. Why this didn't work in the first place, I cannot say (maybe the installer was booted in legacy BIOS mode; in your other question you state that you "forced" an EFI install, this could also be the cause).